Cannot find a value for the configuration variable 'INFURA_API_KEY'
I am setting up a npx hardhat project and it can't read my .env vars.
Error HH1201: Cannot find a value for the configuration variable 'INFURA_API_KEY'.
I looked at example to read the env vars. Any ideas?
The hardhat.config.js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

const { vars } = require("hardhat/config");
const INFURA_API_KEY = vars.get("INFURA_API_KEY");
const SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY = vars.get("SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY");
const MAINNET_PRIVATE_KEY = vars.get("MAINNET_PRIVATE_KEY");
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = vars.get("ETHERSCAN_API_KEY");

module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.24",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1000,
      },
    },
  },
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: `https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [MAINNET_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      sepolia: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
      mainnet: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },
  },
};


The .env file
SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY=0x1123456
MAINNET_PRIVATE_KEY=0x1123456
ETHERSCAN_API_KEY=ERTGHJK...
INFURA_API_KEY=qwertyu...

The file tree
├── contracts
│   ├── Arbitrage.sol
│   └── Lock.sol
├── .env
├── hardhat.config.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── README.md

And package.json
{
  "name": "hardhat-project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^5.0.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.22.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5"
  }
}


There are two ways of accessing environment variables in your hardhat.config.js file:
Using .env file:
When using the .env file, you need to add this line to your hardhat.config.js file:
require("dotenv").config();

And, then you can access the environment variables using process.env.VARIABLE_NAME.
Your revised hardhat.config.js would be:
require("dotenv").config();

const INFURA_API_KEY = process.env.INFURA_API_KEY;
const SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY;
const MAINNET_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.MAINNET_PRIVATE_KEY;
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;

module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.24",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1000,
      },
    },
  },
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: `https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [MAINNET_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      sepolia: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
      mainnet: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },
  },
};

Using configuration variables:
When accessing the configuration variables using:
const { vars } = require("hardhat/config");

Then, you don't need any .env file and explicitly define the environment variables there. Instead, you've to set them interactively from the terminal using the command for each of your environment variable, like:
$ npx hardhat vars set INFURA_API_KEY
✔ Enter value: ********************************

$ npx hardhat vars set SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY
✔ Enter value: ********************************

$ npx hardhat vars set MAINNET_PRIVATE_KEY
✔ Enter value: ********************************

$ npx hardhat vars set ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
✔ Enter value: ********************************

P.S., This is a more encrypted and secure way of storing environment variables, as they are not directly stored as plain text in any .env file, so they can't be accidentally pushed to a repository.
